# MPMoviePlayerController not working on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios5

I'm using MPMoviePlayerController to play a ".3gp" video , i get the data from the server and save it in NSData object then i write it to a file inside the Document directory here's my code

in .h i defined videoPlayer as

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {
   MPMoviePlayerController* videoPlayer;   }
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController* videoPlayer;
```

in .m file

```
-(void)videoWillStartPlayWithUrl:(NSData *)d
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,      YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myMove.3gp"];

    [d writeToFile:path atomically:YES];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    adBannerView.hidden = YES;
    self.videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    self.videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;  
    self.videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;  

    [self.videoPlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];

    [self.view addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];  

    [self.videoPlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [self.videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.videoPlayer play];

}
```

**it's working perfectly in iOS < 5  but in iOS 5 it just shows a black screen and quit directly**  and i can't seem to figure the problem that prevent the video from playing in iOS 5 any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of searching and debugging the problem turned out to be related to the codecs of the videos i was trying to play ,

while they worked perfectly in iOS 4 , iOS 5 requires the special codecs of the  .3GP videos as mentioned in the [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). programming guide , so the solution was to change the codec of my videos and the code worked perfectly on iOS 5

Answer (score 0):

In Your header file do this :-

```
MPMoviePlayerController *myPlayer;
```

and change your property to :-

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *myPlayer;
```

Initiate the moviePlayer as follows :-

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:Url];
self.myPlayer= player;
```

You might have your arc enabled.

Comment: should i send messages to player or self.myPlayer ?      [self.myPlayer play] or [player play]

Comment: self.myplayer..also the only point to note is that you have to use strong keyword here

Comment: thnx a lot but it's not working ! the  "MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification" is received and the player is removed from the View without displaying anything but the player interface and a loading indicator at the top of it ! any other thoughts  ?